# How to get TensorFlow to detect all GPUs on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tensorflow, keras

I am running an lstm net on ec2 p2.8xlarge. Of course I'd like to take advantage of all the gpus available(8). I an run it on one gpu easily, but not more. I get the following error when calling "multi_gpu_model":

"To call `multi_gpu_model` with `gpus=8`, we expect the following devices to be available: ['/cpu:0', '/gpu:0', '/gpu:1', '/gpu:2', '/gpu:3', '/gpu:4', '/gpu:5', '/gpu:6', '/gpu:7']. However this machine only has: ['/cpu:0']. Try reducing `gpus`."

When I type nvidia-smi, all 8 gpus show up in terminal. How can I add these to my tf (keras) environment?

when I run `device_lib.list_local_devices()` in jupyter notebook it returns only CPU0 when it should return 8 GPUs too. Here is the relevant bit of code:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
# define the checkpoint
filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
# fit the model
model=multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=8)

model.fit(X, y, epochs=20, batch_size=128, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://mortada.net/tips-for-running-tensorflow-with-gpu-support-on-aws.html

Comment: Hmmm...I went through the top of the article, but unfortunately no change. I've got everything I need installed (i think) as it does definitely run on a single gpu if I my call to remove multi_gpu_model(). I can validate this with nvidia-smi. It shows ~80% gpu usage on the last gpu when I'm training the NN.

Comment: Checkout the new P3 instance and the Volta optimized TensorFlow container provided by NVIDIA NGC.

Comment: Has anyone solved this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: I was unable to solve this as of 6/2018